# Dynamically color svg elements on canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

I am trying to draw [this chess piece](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Category:SVG_chess_pieces#/media/File:Chess_kdt45.svg) to a Canvas element, and I want to give it a custom fill color.

I tried the following to add the svg to DOM and it worked.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>    
</body>
<script>
    window.onload = function(){
        const color = "#02B09F"

        const svg_string = `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="45" height="45"><g style="fill:none; fill-opacity:1; fill-rule:evenodd; stroke:${color}; stroke-width:1.5; stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:4; stroke-dasharray:none; stroke-opacity:1;"><path d="M 22.5,11.63 L 22.5,6" style="fill:none; stroke:${color}; stroke-linejoin:miter;" id="path6570"/><path d="M 22.5,25 C 22.5,25 27,17.5 25.5,14.5 C 25.5,14.5 24.5,12 22.5,12 C 20.5,12 19.5,14.5 19.5,14.5 C 18,17.5 22.5,25 22.5,25" style="fill:${color};fill-opacity:1; stroke-linecap:butt; stroke-linejoin:miter;"/><path d="M 12.5,37 C 18,40.5 27,40.5 32.5,37 L 32.5,30 C 32.5,30 41.5,25.5 38.5,19.5 C 34.5,13 25,16 22.5,23.5 L 22.5,27 L 22.5,23.5 C 20,16 10.5,13 6.5,19.5 C 3.5,25.5 12.5,30 12.5,30 L 12.5,37" style="fill:${color}; stroke:${color};"/><path d="M 20,8 L 25,8" style="fill:none; stroke:${color}; stroke-linejoin:miter;"/><path d="M 32,29.5 C 32,29.5 40.5,25.5 38.03,19.85 C 34.15,14 25,18 22.5,24.5 L 22.5,26.6 L 22.5,24.5 C 20,18 10.85,14 6.97,19.85 C 4.5,25.5 13,29.5 13,29.5" style="fill:none; stroke:#ffffff;"/><path d="M 12.5,30 C 18,27 27,27 32.5,30 M 12.5,33.5 C 18,30.5 27,30.5 32.5,33.5 M 12.5,37 C 18,34 27,34 32.5,37" style="fill:none; stroke:#ffffff;"/></g></svg>`        
        
        const parser = new DOMParser();
        const doc = parser.parseFromString(svg_string, "image/svg+xml");                
        document.querySelector('body').appendChild(doc.firstChild)        
    }
</script>
</html>
```

but using drawImage with doc.firstChild didn't work, it gave me the following error:

**CanvasRenderingContext2D.drawImage: Argument 1 could not be converted to any of: HTMLImageElement, SVGImageElement, HTMLCanvasElement, HTMLVideoElement, ImageBitmap.**

the code:

```
        const color = "#02B09F"

        const svg_string = `<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="45" height="45"><g style="fill:none; fill-opacity:1; fill-rule:evenodd; stroke:${color}; stroke-width:1.5; stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:4; stroke-dasharray:none; stroke-opacity:1;"><path d="M 22.5,11.63 L 22.5,6" style="fill:none; stroke:${color}; stroke-linejoin:miter;" id="path6570"/><path d="M 22.5,25 C 22.5,25 27,17.5 25.5,14.5 C 25.5,14.5 24.5,12 22.5,12 C 20.5,12 19.5,14.5 19.5,14.5 C 18,17.5 22.5,25 22.5,25" style="fill:${color};fill-opacity:1; stroke-linecap:butt; stroke-linejoin:miter;"/><path d="M 12.5,37 C 18,40.5 27,40.5 32.5,37 L 32.5,30 C 32.5,30 41.5,25.5 38.5,19.5 C 34.5,13 25,16 22.5,23.5 L 22.5,27 L 22.5,23.5 C 20,16 10.5,13 6.5,19.5 C 3.5,25.5 12.5,30 12.5,30 L 12.5,37" style="fill:${color}; stroke:${color};"/><path d="M 20,8 L 25,8" style="fill:none; stroke:${color}; stroke-linejoin:miter;"/><path d="M 32,29.5 C 32,29.5 40.5,25.5 38.03,19.85 C 34.15,14 25,18 22.5,24.5 L 22.5,26.6 L 22.5,24.5 C 20,18 10.85,14 6.97,19.85 C 4.5,25.5 13,29.5 13,29.5" style="fill:none; stroke:#ffffff;"/><path d="M 12.5,30 C 18,27 27,27 32.5,30 M 12.5,33.5 C 18,30.5 27,30.5 32.5,33.5 M 12.5,37 C 18,34 27,34 32.5,37" style="fill:none; stroke:#ffffff;"/></g></svg>`        
        
        const parser = new DOMParser();
        const doc = parser.parseFromString(svg_string, "image/svg+xml");                        

        let canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
        canvas.width = 100;
        canvas.height = 100;
    
        let cx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        cx.drawImage(doc.firstChild, 0, 0)
```

any idea how to fix it, or if you know a better way to color SVGs using javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just make a function and replace the colors. [test code here](https://jsfiddle.net/q0js87tv/)

```js
function renderChess(white = '#FFFFFF', black = '#000000'){
   return '<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="45" height="45"> <g style="fill:none; fill-opacity:1; fill-rule:evenodd; stroke:' + black + '; stroke-width:1.5; stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:4; stroke-dasharray:none; stroke-opacity:1;"> <path d="M 22.5,11.63 L 22.5,6" style="fill:none; stroke:' + black + '; stroke-linejoin:miter;" id="path6570"/> <path d="M 22.5,25 C 22.5,25 27,17.5 25.5,14.5 C 25.5,14.5 24.5,12 22.5,12 C 20.5,12 19.5,14.5 19.5,14.5 C 18,17.5 22.5,25 22.5,25" style="fill:' + black + ';fill-opacity:1; stroke-linecap:butt; stroke-linejoin:miter;"/> <path d="M 12.5,37 C 18,40.5 27,40.5 32.5,37 L 32.5,30 C 32.5,30 41.5,25.5 38.5,19.5 C 34.5,13 25,16 22.5,23.5 L 22.5,27 L 22.5,23.5 C 20,16 10.5,13 6.5,19.5 C 3.5,25.5 12.5,30 12.5,30 L 12.5,37" style="fill:' + black + '; stroke:' + black + ';"/> <path d="M 20,8 L 25,8" style="fill:none; stroke:' + black + '; stroke-linejoin:miter;"/> <path d="M 32,29.5 C 32,29.5 40.5,25.5 38.03,19.85 C 34.15,14 25,18 22.5,24.5 L 22.5,26.6 L 22.5,24.5 C 20,18 10.85,14 6.97,19.85 C 4.5,25.5 13,29.5 13,29.5" style="fill:none; stroke:' + white + ';"/> <path d="M 12.5,30 C 18,27 27,27 32.5,30 M 12.5,33.5 C 18,30.5 27,30.5 32.5,33.5 M 12.5,37 C 18,34 27,34 32.5,37" style="fill:none; stroke:' + white + ';"/> </g> </svg>';
}

window.onload = function(){
        const color = "#02B09F"

        const svg_string = renderChess(color, 'black');  
        
        const parser = new DOMParser();
        const doc = parser.parseFromString(svg_string, "image/svg+xml");                
        document.querySelector('body').appendChild(doc.firstChild)        
    }
```